# Do any of the Secret Wars (2015) tie-in stories spoil the main Secret Wars story?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, secret-wars

The final issue of *Secret Wars* (2015) has been delayed.  I am reading via trade paperback/hardcover collected releases.  Many of the tie-in stories are being released now in these collected releases.  But I can't even start reading the main *Secret Wars* story until that final issue is released, which then allows Marvel to publish the collection.  Since I'm going to have quite a few tie-in collections sitting around, I want to know if I can read them without having the early events of *Secret Wars* spoiled.

Do the *Secret Wars* tie-ins spoil the events in the main event book?  (be sure to use spoiler tags in your answer if you're going to be super specific)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Star Lord & Kitty Pryde*** spoils *Secret Wars #4*.

***Seige #4*** has parts that overlap with *Secret Wars #6*, but goes best if read first.

Likewise, ***Thors #4*** has parts that overlap with *Secret Wars #7*, but goes best if read first.

The last issue (#5) of ***Old Man Logan***, ***A-Force***,  ***Weirdworld***, and especially ***Ultimate End*** all to a certain degree spoil the ending to *Secret Wars* in the process of trying to pave the way to the *All New All Different*.

**Last Days of Silver Surfer #15** also takes place following the ending of Secret Wars.

Besides for that, most of the tie-in's never even mention events from the main book or vise versa.