# What is the reading order for the 2015 Secret Wars event?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, secret-wars

I've seen a few supposed reading orders and checklists, but most of them differ in spots.

What is the full in-universe chronological reading order, including tie-ins and lead-ins for the 2015 Marvel Secret Wars crossover event?

Comment: The event is not finished yet.

Comment: Isn't it? Some of the new #1's are on sale now. It was my understanding that those were all post-Secret Wars

Comment: These new number ones are chronologically after the event but the issues of the main event series were delayed, Marvel just decided to push ahead with their release.

Comment: @phantom42 Marvel had to start publishing the new #1s, since those are their usual weekly comics.  They couldn't delay dozens of comics to wait for *Secret Wars*. :/

Comment: [Related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109326/do-any-of-the-secret-wars-2015-tie-in-stories-spoil-the-main-secret-wars-story)

Comment: Is there a way I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

[Comic Book Herald](http://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-marvel-reading-order-guide/secret-wars-reading-order/battleworld-warzone-last-days-checklists/) has a good list:

> ### Secret Wars Trade Reading Order
>
> While the extremely dedicated can follow my issue by issue reading list below, there is some more flexibility with a trade reading order.
>
> For the most part, Secret Wars is deceptively easy. You can read the Last Days tie-ins first, then the main Secret Wars event up to issue #6, then read any Secret Wars tie-in trade as it catches your interest (my trade power rankings can help), then come back to Secret Wars #7 to #9. A small handful of tie-ins have ‘epilogue’ issues, all of which are noted below.
>
> There are minor to medium continuity incongruities that will arise with this method, and if you’re worried about that, I highly recommend the issue by issue list below. If not, this trade reading order should fit your needs nicely!
>
> 1. Secret Wars #0 to #1
> 2. Deadpool’s Secret Secret Wars
>
> Note: Technically Deadpool’s tie-in occurs during the original Secret Wars, aka the mid-80’s. Chronologically it occurs prior to Secret Wars (2015), but that’s a weird place to start.
>
> 3. Captain America & the Mighty Avengers Vol. 2: Last Days
> 4. Black Widow Vol. 3: Last Days
> 5. Loki: Agent of Asgard Vol. 3: Last Days
> 6. Ms. Marvel Vol. 4: Last Days
> 7. Magneto Vol. 4: Last Days
> 8. The Punisher Vol. 3: Last Days
> 9. Silver Surfer Vol. 3: Last Days
>
> Note: Save the final issue of Silver Surfer (#15) for an epilogue to Secret Wars #9.
>
> 10. Secret Wars #2 to #6
>
> Note that Secret Wars is a nine issue event (ten if you count FCBD issue #0). I recommend going no further than issue #6 in the main event before tackling your tie-ins of your choice.
>
> 11. Tie-ins
>
>     - Secret Wars Journal/Battleworld
>     - Master of Kung Fu: Battleworld
>     - A-Force
>
>     Note: Save the final issue of A-Force (#5) for an epilogue to Secret Wars #9.
>
>     - Planet Hulk
>     - Spider-Verse
>     - Inhumans: Attilan Rising
>     - M.O.D.O.K. Assassin
>
>     Note: MODOK Assassin (a personal favorite) can be read in its entirety prior to Secret Wars #4.
>
>     - Infinity Gauntlet
>     - Old Man Logan
>
>     Note: Save the final issue of Old Man Logan (#5) for an epilogue to Secret Wars #9.
>
>     - Inferno
>     - Secret Wars 2099
>     - Where Monsters Dwell
>     - X-Men ‘92
>     - X-Men: Years of Future Past
>     - X-Tinction Agenda
>     - Giant-Size Little Marvel: AvX
>     - Future Imperfect
>     - Spider-Man: Renew Your Vows
>     - Armor Wars
>     - Marvel Zombies: Battleworld
>     - Ghost Racers
>     - Weirdworld
>
>     Note: Save the final issue of Weirdworld (#5) for an epilogue to Secret Wars #9.
>
>     - 1602 Witch Hunter Angela
>     - Captain Marvel & the Carol Corps
>     - Mrs. Deadpool and the Howling Commandos
>     - Thors
>     - Runaways
>     - Squadron Sinister
>     - Age of Ultron vs. Marvel Zombies
>     - Age of Apocalypse
>     - E is for Extinction
>     - Civil War
>     - Guardians of Knowhere
>     - Korvac Saga
>     - Red Skull
>     - Spider-Island
>     - Star-Lord & Kitty Pride
>     - Marvel 1872
>     - House of M
>     - Hail Hydra
>     - Siege: Battleworld
>     - Ultimate End
> 12. Secret Wars #7 to #9
> 13. Epilogue Issues

He also has an issue-by-issue list.